# How to make bold text with Android Data Binding Library

Tags: android, android-databinding

Pretty basic, I want to make a title of a message bold based on whether the text it is read or not. I can't seem to find a solution for this.

Here is my XML code:

```
            <TextView
                android:text="@{message.title}"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timestamp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle='@{message.isRead() ? "bold" : "normal"}'
                android:textColor='@{message.isRead() ? 0xff313131 : 0xff0662ab}' />
```

Th colorchange is working great, only the bold text is giving me some problems.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:textStyle' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.TextView.
>   file:D:......xml
>   loc:39:41 - 39:79
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: Is bold text working if you just set it statically, not with data binding?

Comment: Yes, its working then

Comment: Ill edit in the error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ended up using the following code, it implements DataBinding.

```
public abstract class BindingAdapter {
    @android.databinding.BindingAdapter("android:typeface")
    public static void setTypeface(TextView v, String style) {
        switch (style) {
            case "bold":
                v.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                break;
            default:
                v.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML

```
<TextView
    android:text="@{bericht.titel}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timestamp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor='@{bericht.isGelezen() ? 0xff313131 : 0xff0662ab}'
    android:typeface='@{bericht.isGelezen() ? "normal" : "bold"}' />
```

Comment: This is the correct solution but it could use a small adjustment:
Bind with android:textStyle and use the textStyle attribute in your XML.

Comment: I keep this static method in viewmodel class 

public abstract static class BindingAdapter {
        @android.databinding.BindingAdapter("android:typeface")
        public static void setTypeface(TextView v, String style) {
            switch (style) {
                case "bold":
                    v.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    break;
                default:
                    v.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }  

and into xml
android:typeface='@{bericht.isGelezen() ? "normal" : "bold"}'

Answer (score 33):

An easy way

```
public class TextViewBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("isBold")
    public static void setBold(TextView view, boolean isBold) {
        if (isBold) {
            view.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        } else {
            view.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:isBold="@{item.bold}"/>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, the accepted answer is out-of-date.

Answer (score 17):

You can do this without creating an adapter.

Import Typeface to your XML

```
<data>
    <import type="android.graphics.Typeface" />
...
</data>
```

Use the attribute `android:typeface` with [Typeface.defaultFromStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface#defaultFromStyle(int)):

```
android:typeface="@{Typeface.defaultFromStyle(message.isRead() ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL)}"
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Saif Bechan is correct in his answer, I made a slight change to facilitate databinding from a view model.

```
public abstract class BindingAdapter {
    @android.databinding.BindingAdapter("app:textStyle")
    public static void setTextStyle(TextView v, int style) {
        v.setTypeface(null, style);
    }
}
```

Then you bring in the `app` namespace to your XML

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
...
</layout>
```

Create a binding in the view model

```
@Bindable
public int getValueFormat() {
    String message = getMyObject().getValue();
    if (message == MyObject.DEFAULT_VALUE)
        return Typeface.ITALIC;

    return Typeface.NORMAL;
}
```

Now you can bind this directly

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:textStyle="@{viewModel.valueFormat}"
    android:text="@{viewModel.value}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same problem this week, I was trying to use the `view.setTypeface()` method, but I wanted to keep the font style in my case. It turns out that the bold style worked when I passed null in the setTypeFace method, but...passing null can make changes in the font style (was not looking at the same). When I tried to use the same font style and set the view to bold it was not working.

To achieve what I wanted, since I was not succeeding in using this method I just change the font style when the bold is required, see my code:

```
@BindingAdapter("boldOrRegular")
@JvmStatic
    fun TextView.boldOrRegular(isBold: Boolean) {
        typeface = if (isBold) {
            ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont_bold)
        } else {
            ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont_regular)
        }
    }
```

I hope that this can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

you just has to import Typeface to the xml file and make your check like this

```
    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.example.VM" />

    <import type="android.graphics.Typeface" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="@{vm.isBold ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL}"/>
```

Comment: didn't work for me. getting Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.TextView android:textStyle> that accepts parameter type 'int'. It seems it needs a custom adapter after all.

Answer (score -5):

You need to create `getMessageStyle` into your message Object :

```
public String getMessageStyle() {
    return isRead() ? "bold" : "normal";
}
```

---

then use as below into your code :

```
<TextView
    android:text="@{message.title}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timestamp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="@{message.getMessageStyle()}"
    android:textColor="@{message.isRead() ? 0xff313131 : 0xff0662ab}" />
```

Comment: I tried this, this did not work. I have found another way of doing this. I will post my answer shortly.